# How to reverse an int in python?

Tags: python, reverse

I'm creating a python script which prints out the whole song of '99 bottles of beer', but reversed. The only thing I cannot reverse is the numbers, being integers, not strings.

This is my full script,

```
def reverse(str):
   return str[::-1]

def plural(word, b):
    if b != 1:
        return word + 's'
    else:
        return word

def line(b, ending):
    print b or reverse('No more'), plural(reverse('bottle'), b), reverse(ending)

for i in range(99, 0, -1):
    line(i, "of beer on the wall")
    line(i, "of beer"
    print reverse("Take one down, pass it around")
    line(i-1, "of beer on the wall \n")
```

I understand my reverse function takes a string as an argument, however I do not know how to take in an integer, or , how to reverse the integer later on in the script.

Comment: What output do you expect for 10 or 20 or 30 ...?

Comment: 10 would be 01, 56 would be 65 etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are approaching this in quite an odd way. You already have a reversing function, so why not make `line` just build the line *the normal way around*?

```
def line(bottles, ending):
    return "{0} {1} {2}".format(bottles, 
                                plural("bottle", bottles), 
                                ending)
```

Which runs like:

```
>>> line(49, "of beer on the wall")
'49 bottles of beer on the wall'
```

Then pass the result to `reverse`:

```
>>> reverse(line(49, "of beer on the wall"))
'llaw eht no reeb fo selttob 94'
```

This makes it much easier to test each part of the code separately and see what's going on when you put it all together.

Answer (score 18):

Without converting the number to a string:

```
def reverse_number(n):
    r = 0
    while n > 0:
        r *= 10
        r += n % 10
        n /= 10
    return r

print(reverse_number(123))
```

Comment: +1 `reverse_number(10) == 1` which is a proper number without leading zeros.

Comment: Although in this case I think that's a bad thing!

Comment: So, this is not the answer, because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953303/how-to-reverse-an-int-in-python?noredirect=1#comment38788948_24953303).

Comment: Use `n //= 10` instead of `n /= 10`. This will result small number and will not return a ideal reversed number, a infinite number **inf**.

Comment: as @BeatrizFonseca said, especially when using Python 3 you have to use `//`

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

```
>>> x = 123
>>> str(x)
'123'
>>> str(x)[::-1]
'321'
```

Comment: Negative numbers should be considered

Answer (score 4):

best way is

```
x=12345
a=str(x)[::-1]\\ In this process i have create string of inverse of integer (a="54321")
a=int(a) \\ Here i have converted string a in integer
```

or
one line code is

```
a=int(str(x)[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse_number(n):
    r = 0
    while n > 0:
        r = (r*10) + (n % 10)
        print(r)
        r *=10
        n //= 10
    return r


print(reverse_number(123))
```

Comment: Reversing a number try this, may help you better

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(x):
        re = 0
        negative = x < 0
        MAX_BIG = 2 ** 31 -1
        MIN_BIG = -2 ** 31 
        x = abs(x)

        while x != 0:
            a = int(x % 10)
            re = re * 10 + a
            x = int(x // 10)

        reverse = -1 * re if negative else re
        return 0 if reverse < MIN_BIG or reverse > MAX_BIG else reverse
```

this is for 32 - bit integer ( -2^31 ; 2^31-1 )

Comment: Python doesn't have integer size limits so half of this code is useless :/

Answer (score 0):

You can cast an integer to string with str(i) and then use your reverse function.

The following line should do what you are looking for:

```
    def line(b, ending):
        print reverse(str(b)) or reverse('No more'), plural(reverse('bottle'),reverse(str(b))), reverse(ending)
```

Comment: This gives e.g. `'74 elttobs llaw eht no reeb fo'`, rather than `'llaw eht no reeb fo elttobs 74'`

Comment: You are right @jonrsharpe, I didn't look at the result in the first place and only answered his/her explicite question. I just reversed the number in his code. 
Your previous answer is the way I would choose(reverse the string as a whole), I just wanted to answer the implied question :-)

Comment: Just for the sake of being technically correct ("the best kind of correct" <g>): there's *no* such thing as a "cast" (in the C / C++ / Java etc meaning) in Python. `str(i)` instanciate a new `str` object using the string representation of `i` as value.

Answer (score 0):

Original number is taken in a

```
a = 123
```

We convert the int to string ,then reverse it and again convert in int and store reversed number in b

`b = int("".join(reversed(str(a))))`

Print the values of a and b
`print(a,b)`

Comment: This ignores 0 if there is a 0

Comment: and if you are going to convert int to string anyways then why not use slicing, its considerably faster than join

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_number(n):
r = 0
while n > 0:
    r *= 10
    r += n % 10
    n /= 10
return r
```

print(reverse_number(123))

This code will not work if the number ends with zeros, example 100 and 1000 return 1

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(num):
  rev = 0
  while(num != 0):
      reminder = num % 10
      rev = (rev * 10 ) + reminder
      num = num // 10 
  print ("Reverse number is  : " , rev )
 
num=input("enter number : ")
reverse(int(num))
```

#/   always results into float

#//  division that results into whole number adjusted to the left in the number line

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should be good to reverse your positive integer.
You can use it as a function in your code.

```
  n = input()  # input is always taken as a string
  rev = int(str(n)[::-1])
```

If you are having `n` as integer then you need to specify it as str here as shown. This is the quickest way to reverse a positive integer

Comment: Please don't randomly bold text in an answer. The # is treated as a start of heading, and not as a comment.

Comment: @AlBlue - My Apologies. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math

def Function(inputt):

    a = 1
    input2 = inputt

    while(input2 > 9):

        input2 = input2/10
        a = a + 1

    print("There are ", a, " numbers ")
    N = 10  
    m = 1
    print(" THe reverse numbers are: ")

    for i in range(a):
        l = (inputt%N)/m
        print(math.floor(l), end = '')
        N = N*10
        m = m*10
    print(" \n")
    return 0
enter = int(input("Enter the number: "))
print(Function(enter))
```

Answer (score 0):

More robust solution to handle negative numbers:

```
def reverse_integer(num):
    sign = [1,-1][num < 0]
    output = sign * int(str(abs(num))[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy and fast way to do it is as follows:

```py
    def reverse(x: int|str) -> int:
        reverse_x = int(''.join([dgt for dgt in reversed(num:=str(x)) if dgt != '-']))
        if '-' in num:
            reverse_x = -reverse_x'
        return reverse_x
```

First we create a list (using list comprehension) of the digits in reverse order. However, we must exclude the sign (otherwise the number would turn out like [3, 2, 1, -]). We now turn the list into a string using the ''.join() method.

Next we check if the original number had a negative sign in it. If it did, we would add a negative sign to reverse_x.

Answer (score -1):

Easily you can write this class:

```
class reverse_number:
            def __init__(self,rvs_num):
                self.rvs_num = rvs_num
                rvs_ed = int(str(rvs_num)[::-1])
                print(rvs_ed)
```

You can use it by writing:

```
reverse_number(your number)
```

Answer (score -2):

I have written it in a different way, but it works

```
def isPalindrome(x: int) -> bool:

    if x<0:
        return False
    elif x<10:
        return True
    else:
        rev=0
        rem = x%10
        quot = x//10
        rev = rev*10+rem
        while (quot>=10):
           rem = quot%10
           quot = quot//10
           rev = rev*10+rem
        rev = rev*10+quot
        if rev==x:
            return True
        else:
            return False

res=isPalindrome(1221)
```