# reverse an integer in python

Tags: python, arrays, reverse

I have this code here, I did it so it can reverse an integer. My problem is that I don't know if this is the best solution I can get. It runs in O(n).

```
def int_reversed(integer):
    integer = str(integer)
    # turning the integer into a list
    each_num = []
    for i in integer:
        each_num.append(i)


    index_one = 0
    index_final = len(integer)-1

    # cheking if they are the same

    while index_final > index_one:
        each_num[index_one], each_num[index_final] =each_num[index_final], each_num[index_one]
        index_one = index_one + 1
        index_final = index_final - 1
    return int(''.join(each_num))
```

I also did this but I was trying to do it in an algorithmic way first:

```
def reverse_int(num):
    num = str(num)
    reversed_int = num[::-1]
    return reversed_int
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse an int in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953303/how-to-reverse-an-int-in-python)

Comment: If your code works and you're are asking for a (performance) review, then this is not the right place.

Comment: What is n? And what is your question?

Comment: The second option is definitely better, both in terms of code brevity/readability and performance.  I’d write it more simply yet though: `return int(str(num)[::-1])`

Comment: (beware negative numbers though!)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this "algorithmically" then you could do this:

```
def reverse_int(n):
    v = 0
    if n < 0:
        n = -n
        m = -1
    else:
        m = 1
    while n > 0:
        v *= 10
        v += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return v * m

print(reverse_int(-123))
```

**Output:**

```
-321
```